# MVC 4 dedicated configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to add some constants to MVC 4 project. 
Adding them to  in web.config will work:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyConst1" value="123"/>
    <add key="MyConst2" value="321"/>
    <add key="MyConst3" value="234"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Is there a way to create separate config file for this constants?

Comment: Why you want to do that? Web.config is the place for this.

Comment: @Fals, OP asking **how** and you ask him **why**? whyyy?

Comment: @meda I can ask anything I want! That's my answer... Be polite is far away from you!

Comment: @Fals aww dont be sensitive, nothing is impolite in my comments ;)

Comment: @Fals Using Web.config is Ok. I was just wondering it's possible to use dedicated file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to separate your `appSettings` from web.config, you can store them in a separate file and then specify that in your web.config under `appSettings`'s `configSource` like:

```
<appSettings configSource="MySettings.config" />
```

and then you can have your settings in `MySettings.config` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyConst1" value="123"/>
    <add key="MyConst2" value="321"/>
    <add key="MyConst3" value="234"/>
</appSettings>
```

You may see: [Using configSource to split configuration files](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/04/26/using-configsource-to-split-configuration-files.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you put your code snippet in a file called `appSettings.config`, you can simply reference that file in your web config:

```
<appSettings configSource="appSettings.config" />
```